# React Native Flat List (Infinite Scroll) is returning the duplicate records from Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I was able to get Infinite Scroll working with React Native and Firebase, but there's an issue on retrieving the next 6 documents (limit is set to 6). It returns another 6 once the end of the list is refreshed, but it's the same 6 documents appended to the previous same 6 documents.

I have the startAt increase each time 6 records are rendering and the startAt is increasing at the right amount. Not sure if I'm missing something or if it could be an async issue?

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, FlatList, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../config/config';

// Imports: Components
import UserSelector from '../components/UserSelector';
import TitleLarge from '../components/TitleLarge';

// Screen Dimensions
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

// Screen: Flat List (Users)
class FlatListUsers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      startAt: 0,
      limit: 6,
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  // Component Will Mount
  componentWillMount = () => {
    // Firebase: Initialize
    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: `${firebaseConfig.apiKey}`,
      authDomain: `${firebaseConfig.authDomain}`,
      databaseURL: `${firebaseConfig.databaseURL}`,
      projectId: `${firebaseConfig.projectId}`,
      storageBucket: `${firebaseConfig.storageBucket}`,
      messagingSenderId: `${firebaseConfig.messagingSenderId}`,
    });
  }

  // Component Did Mount
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.retrieveUsers();
  }

  // Retrieve Users
  retrieveUsers = async () => {
    try {
      // Set State: Loading
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      // Firebase: Database + Settings
      const db = firebase.firestore();

      // Query
      console.log('Fetching Users')
      const query = await db.collection('users')
                            .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                            .orderBy('first_name')
                            .startAt(this.state.startAt)
                            .limit(this.state.limit);

      // Query Snapshot
      const querySnapshot = await query.get();

      // Document Data
      console.log('Document Data');
      const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
      // console.log(documentData);

      // Set State: Initial Query
      if (this.state.startAt <= this.state.limit) { 
        // Set State
        this.setState({
          data: documentData,
          startAt: this.state.startAt + this.state.limit + 1,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false,
        })
      }
      // Set State: Refreshing Queries
      else {
        // Set State
        this.setState({
          data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
          startAt: this.state.startAt + this.state.limit + 1,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false,
        })
      }

      // Start At
      console.log(`StartAt: ${this.state.startAt}`);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Retrieve More Users
  retrieveMore = async () => {
    try {
      // Set State + Retrieve Users 
      this.setState({
        loading: true,
      }, async () => {
        await this.retrieveUsers();
      })

      // Set State
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
      })
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Header
  renderHeader = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activityIndicator}>
          <TitleLarge title="Users" />
        </View>
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Render Footer
  renderFooter = () => {
    try {
      // Check If Loading
      if (this.state.loading) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => ( 
            <UserSelector
              key={(item, index) => {
                return item.id;
              }}
              firstName={item.first_name}
              lastName={item.last_name}
              company={item.company}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={( item ) => {
            return item.id;
          }}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onEndReached={this.retrieveMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: height,
    width: width,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0,
  },
  scrollView:{
    height: 'auto',
  },
  UserContainer: {
    width: width,
    marginBottom: 7,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontFamily: 'System',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#222222',
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  activityIndicator: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: '#CED0CE',
  },
});

// Exports
export default FlatListUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

`Flatlist` may call your retrieval method twice. So be sure to use the `loading` prop to prevent the method from running.

```
onEndReached={(foo)=>{
  if (this.state.loading === false){
   this.makeAPizza(foo);
 }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query gets the same results because it always starts at the same offset: `startAt: 0`.

To fix, keep a `pageNumber` in state, advanced as the user scrolls, then `startAt: pageNumber*6`

A few other comments about the code:  State can be simplified...

```
this.state = {
  data: [],
  limit: 6,
  // startAt removed.  start at the end of data
  loading: false
};
```

Don't need `retrieveMore`.  Its the same as `retrieveUsers`.  `retrieveUsers` can be simplified...

```
// Retrieve Users
retrieveUsers = async () => {
  try {
    // Set State: Loading
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // Firebase: Database + Settings
    const db = firebase.firestore();

    // Query
    console.log('Fetching Users')
    const query = await db.collection('users')
                          .where('company', '==', 'Google')
                          .orderBy('first_name')
                          .startAt(this.state.data.length)
                          .limit(this.state.limit);

    // Query Snapshot
    const querySnapshot = await query.get();

    // Document Data
    console.log('Document Data');
    const documentData = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());
    // console.log(documentData);


    // Set State
    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, ...documentData],
      loading: false
    })
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Notice that startAt is computed to be the length of data already retrieved.  This works when data array is empty, also.  Notice that logic to update state after the `get` is the same for the first or nth get: append new data to the existing data.

You don't need `retrieveMore`.  Its the same as `retrieveUsers`.  `retrieveUsers` can be simplified...

```
// ...
onEndReached={this.retrieveUsers}
```

Comment: I've got startAt in the state already (this.state.startAt) and that's updating by 6 each time the function executes. So startAt goes from 0 to 6 and so on. Am I missing something on that?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your logic that advances startAt.  Reviewing more carefully, there's some simplification that should make the code easier to debug (at least, maybe it will uncover a fix).  A key idea is that startAt needn't (shouldn't, I would argue) be computed in advance.  Always start at the end index of data that is present.  Also, removed a few logic paths that I think are extraneous.